# Memory issue in mono touch application

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

We have a mono touch application that contains lots of `UIImage` and `UIView` objects. When we install the application (IPA) file in iPad (Version1) then start working, if we continue working for 10 to 20 minutes continuously then it crashed due to low memory.

> We also tried Intruments profile to track heap allocations but it
>   showing memory keep on increasing for each screen navigation. We
>   disposed all the allocated objects in **viewDidDisappear** and even though
>   memory not getting decreased. We also try to manually force garbage
>   collector to collect the garbage through **GC.Collect()**, but it also not
>   working.

**Is this a bug in mono touch? or we missed memory management techniques?**

Please help me to fix the Low memory warning issue..

Thanks

Comment: 1. Are you using ARC?
2. Are you storing the images in your app bundle from getting them from webserver?
3. How are you maintaining the View hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your issue, but this article covers memory best practices. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/memory_perf_best_practices.   Some may only apply to xamarin's gc, but at least half are fairly generalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with `UIImage` and `UIImageView` you should wrap your code into `using` statements or dispose the images manually if you don't need them anymore. The reason is that the managed version of UIImage basically only consists of 4 bytes, a pointer to a memory region that holds the image data.
The image itself is unmanaged. This means that there is no pressure on the GC because it only sees the managed world.
If you cannot do that because you need to hold all the image data in memory, you'll need to rethink your design. iOS devices only have a very limited amount of RAM and just because you can apply the full power of .NET to the device, doesn't mean that you also should do that. Try to be a good memory citizen.

```
using(UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(...))
{
  // Process the image.
}

// Here, the image data will be freed.
```